# How to set the exit status in a Groovy Script

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, exit-code

We have a Groovy Script that exits with a `status` of `0` when everything worked and a `non-0 status` for different types of failure conditions. For example if the script took a user and an email address as arguments it would exit with a `status` of `1` for an invalid user, and a `status` of `2` for an invalid email address format. We use `System.exit(statusCode)` for this. This works fine, but makes the the script difficult to write test cases for.

In a test we create our `GroovyShell`, create our `Binding` and call `shell.run(script,args)`. For tests that assert failure conditions, the `System.exit()` causes the JVM (and the test) to exit.

Are there alternatives to using `System.exit()` to exit a Groovy Script? I experimented with throwing uncaught exceptions, but that clutters the output and always makes the status code 1.

In our test cases I have also experimented with using `System.metaClass.static.invokeMethod` to change the behavior of `System.exit()` to not exit the JVM, but that seems like an ugly hack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

imho `System.metaClass.static.invokeMethod` looks fine. It's test, and hacking is fine here.

Also you can create your own wrapper around it, like:

```
class ExitUtils {

    static boolean enabled = true

    static exit(int code) {
        if (!ExitUtils.enabled) {
            return  //TODO set some flag?
        }
        System.exit(code)
    }

}
```

and disable it for tests.

Comment: Thanks. I cleaned up our `System.metaClass.static.invokeMethod` work and it looked a lot less hacky.

Comment: Just a warning to others who attempt this in a Jenkins pipeline groovy script step, this will kill whole Jenkins process.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the technique we eventually used.

We can't just ignore a call to `System.exit()` since the script would continue to run. Instead we want to throw an exception with the desired status code. We throw a (custom) `ProgramExitException` when `System.exit()` is called in our tests

```
class ProgramExitException extends RuntimeException {

    int statusCode

    public ProgramExitException(int statusCode) {
        super("Exited with " + statusCode)
        this.statusCode = statusCode
    }
}
```

then we intercept `System.exit()` to throw this exception

```
/**
 * Make System.exit throw ProgramExitException to fake exiting the VM
 */
System.metaClass.static.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
    if (name == 'exit')
        throw new ProgramExitException(args[0])
    def validMethod =  System.metaClass.getStaticMetaMethod(name, args)
    if (validMethod != null) {
        validMethod.invoke(delegate, args)
    }
    else {
        return  System.metaClass.invokeMissingMethod(delegate, name, args)
    }
}
```

and lastly we have `GroovyShell` catch any `ProgramExitException` and return the status code from the `run` method.

```
/**
 * Catch ProgramExitException exceptions to mimic exit status codes
 * without exiting the VM
 */
GroovyShell.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
    def validMethod = GroovyShell.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
    if (validMethod != null) {
        try {
            validMethod.invoke(delegate, args)
        } catch (ProgramExitException e) {
            return e.statusCode
        }
    }
    else {
        return GroovyShell.metaClass.invokeMissingMethod(delegate, name, args)
    }
 }
```

Our tests can stay looking simple, we don't need to change anything in the scripts and we get the behavior we expect from running on the command line.

```
assertEquals 'Unexpected status code', 0, shell.run(script,[arg1, arg2])
assertEquals 'Unexpected status code', 10, shell.run(script,[badarg1, badarg2])
```